Angular component inheritance: will @Component decorator metadata inherited?
I have a parent-component like this:
@Component({
  template: "",
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ImYourFather {}

Now I also have two inheritance components like this:
@Component({
   template: "I'm Luke",
})
export class Luke extends ImYourFather {}

@Component({
   template: "I'm Leia",
})
export class Leia extends ImYourFather {}

What is the changeDetectionStrategy for Luka & Leia?
Will @Component decorator metadata inherited?
Please provide some source to verify the statement! I haven't found anything yet. Thanks.

After seeing different answers, I just tried it out myself.
Result:

The ChangeDetectionStrategy (e. g. "OnPush") is not inheritated by class-inheritance via extend. Although it is inherited by its DOM-parent.


Example
Compare right-comment of this Luke:
<!-- Luke extends ImYourFather / ImYourFather CDS="OnPush" / Luke CDS=<no set> -->
<app-luke></app-luke> <!-- CDS="Default" -->

.. with right-comment of that Luke:
<!-- Deathstar CDS="OnPush" -->
<app-deathstar>
   <!-- Luke extends ImYourFather | ImYourFather CDS="OnPush" | Luke CDS=<no set> -->
   <app-luke></app-luke> <!-- CDS="OnPush" -->
</app-deathstar>

➡ Same Luke, different ChangeDetectionStrategies.

Stackblitz Demo

No, it's not inherited, you have to manually redefine it. My understanding is that dynamic templates and dynamic decorators are not possible because it will prevent code optimization during Angular build (from an earlier comment or post by Matthieu Riegler).
Plus one more thing is, on OOPS inheritance, only the class is inherited, meaning the properties and methods. The decorator does not belong to either of the two, so it's not possible to inherit it.

That's also what I assume. I'm looking for a link that convinces me.

@jaheraho the first part just explained about dynamic templates, but the second paragraph applies to your use case. When we inherit a class, there is no possibility of the decorator being inherited since it lies outside the class, there is no proof needed for that, you can check javascript inheritance to confirm the same!

No, that is not completely correct. If a parent defines the CD strategy as OnPush, all its descendants are marked as OnPush likewise by design.
You are correct though, that there is no explicit inheritance of the metadata.

@PhilippMeissner What is your answer to the headline of this question?

As I said: @NarenMurali is correct about the inheritance of the metadata part (It is not being inherited) Though, every rendered child "uses" the CD strategy of its parent by design.
// Luke / Leia will have the default CD strategy, unless rendered within a parent that has a different CD strategy.
